# sql query with "with and in clause"

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table which store user name, hobby and city .hobby field contain different hobby joined using "," operator eg swimming, basket, cricket. I want to search user name who match at least one hobby according to my search criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have multiple attributes in one column.  That's one of the number one rules of 3nf database design.  Now you have to figure out ways to parse this data.  This issue only gets worse and worse each and every day.  Seperate the hobbies as multiple rows in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JonH that there shouldn't be more than one piece of information in a column.  It stops the row being truly atomic.

But you are where you are, and you can use the [LIKE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/UseLIKEformatchingsubstring.htm) clause to return rows that match a substring within a column.

Something like:

```
select hobbycolumn from hobbytable where hobbycolumn like '%swimming%'
```

for example

Comment: And as @JonH says, the nightmare grows daily. For example, in this case if you search for someone with the hobby "squash", you'll also find anyone with the hobby "squashing bugs in SQL code"...

Comment: @Matt I completely agree - but @bhavishya may not have any say in the database design.

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly you need to restructure your tables if possible. For what you are looking for a possible way would be to have 3 tables. I'm not sure who the city belongs to, so I put it with the user.

1 for `user` with the following cols:

- id
- name
- city

A table for for `hobbies`:

- id
- name

And a `user_hobbies` join table that allows each user to have multiple hobbies, and each hobby to have multiple users:

- id
- user_id (foreign key)
- hobby_id (foreign key)

Then searching for a user with a certain hobby is:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user
INNER JOIN 'user_hobbies' on user_hobbies.user_id=user.id
INNER JOIN 'hobbies' on hobbies.id = user_hobbies.hobby_id
WHERE hobbies.name LIKE "query";
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are stuck in an existing database with the structure you originally asked for, use amelvin's answer.

Comment: but the concern is that if i want to search aganist more than one hobbies then what quesry should be used and i want to display the record which have one hobbies

Comment: Then you would use `WHERE hobbies.name IN ("hobby1", "hobby2", "hobby3", ...)`.

You are basically finding the id of hobbies you want in the hobbies table. Then finding all users with that hobby id in the join table, and finally getting the user information based on the user ids that come back. You might use a `select distinct` or `group by` depending on how you want the data.

Comment: but the concern is end user is selecting hobbies so no of hobbies in set will be decide at run time .so how can i use dynamic no of hobbies

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You are trying to attach hobbies to your user who has none?